# Reducing the number of inner loop iterations in Java for efficiency

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested, continue

This is a mini-challenge from a Java textbook.
Following code can be made more efficient (by reducing the number of inner loop iterations, likely with a `continue` statement).

```
/*
    Use nested loops to find factors of numbers
    between 2 and 100. 

    In the program, the outer loop runs i from 2 through 100. The inner loop successively tests
    all numbers from 2 up to i, printing those that evenly divide i.

*/

class FindFactors {
    public static void main (String args[]) {

        for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
            System.out.print("Factors of " + i + ": ");
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) 
                if ((i%j) == 0) System.out.print(j + " ");


            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

However I try to "simplify" just adds more steps. Any ideas?

Comment: check to see if j is less that i/2 alway you will never have a factor greater than half of i

Comment: you can also calcuate its opposing factor and then you can make the limit the sqrt of i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the inner loop test not all numbers up to i. It is enough if you only test up to half of i

```
 for (int j = 2; j <= i/2; j++)
```

Comment: the greatest factor is equal or lower than half of i

Comment: You can limit the loop further to factors less than or equal to `sqrt(i)` if you pull out the larger factor when you find smaller factor.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
```

Without trying to spoil it, consider a natural number N for which you would calculate the factors. Perhaps you could reduce the amount of numbers you have to check?

Look up factoring integers for more information/different algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Set the length of the inner loop on the square of the index from the outer loop
Each number the max factor its his square